# Confuse about java.util.WeakHashMap behavior？

Tags: reference, jvm, weakhashmap

Here is three cases, Why case1 result is {name=Bob}, however case2 result is {}, case3 is still {name=Bob}. the different between case1 and case2 is putting different key. run at JDK8. Why?

```
    //Case1:
    WeakHashMap<String,String> mapCase1 = new WeakHashMap<>();
    mapCase1.put("name", "Bob");
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println(mapCase1); //{name=Bob}
    //Case2:
    WeakHashMap<String,String> mapCase2 = new WeakHashMap<>();
    mapCase2.put(new String("name"), "Bob");
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println(mapCase2); //{}
    //Case3:
    WeakHashMap<String,String> mapCase3 = new WeakHashMap<>();
    String map3Key = new String("name");
    mapCase3.put(map3Key, "Bob");
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println(mapCase3); //{name=Bob}
```

Comment: What exactly do you find confusing? How do you think this should work and why?

Comment: That’s exactly as expected. The mapping gets removed after garbage collection when the key object is unreachable. It’s generally not recommended to use keys where different object can be equals for a `WeakHashMap`.

Comment: @apangin why the case1 is {name=Bob}， I expect is {}， case2 and case3 is the same，why the result is different？

Comment: @Holger   I expect three case is all {}

Comment: `"name"` is a string literal that evaluates to a canonical object that will stay in the runtime, as long as the code. `String map3Key = new String("name");` assigns the reference to a variable that keeps the object referenced.

Comment: @Holger  "name" stay in the runtime. so key "name" will never be removed from WeakHashMap,. am i right?

Comment: In principle, it could get collected when all code having a reference to it gets garbage collected, which is only possible with custom class loaders, as the entire class loader and all classes it had created must become unreachable. So for most practical cases, `"name"` will never get collected, hence, always stay in the `WeakHashMap` when being used as key.